# Invalid child elements in nuspec when calling Nuget pack

Tags: nuget, nuspec

When I run

```
nuget pack myPackage.nuspec
```

> The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element '**packageSourceUrl**' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'contentFiles, frameworkAssemblies, references, developmentDependency, language, releaseNotes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'.

I understand that the element is invalid and not in the xsd.

My nuspec file has 2 elements in the `metadata` element that will generate errors when creating the nupkg:

```
<metadata>      
  <mailingListUrl>http://example.com</mailingListUrl>
  <packageSourceUrl>https://example.com/</packageSourceUrl>
```

How can I avoid this error with the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailingListUrl` and `packageSourceUrl` **are not a part of the nuspec metadata element**. What are you looking for? The possible nuspec metadata elements are given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec).

Comment: My problem/question stems from the fact that I used a chocolatey nupsec and `nuget pack` didn't understand these chocolatey-specific enhancements